# Keras Prediction one step beyond

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, lstm, keras

I am trying to make time series forecasting with keras. Has any one observe the phenomenon where the model can predict the next value after the current (the one that should predict)?

If in fact I move the the forecasting values one position to the left (starting the predicted dataset from 1 instead of zero)  the accuracy is very good

Here is the code. "ts" is the time series that comes from another time series. The first 4 rows are as below

|  | x |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 596.449044603317 |
| 1 | 579.397435343439 |
| 2 | 564.145409470115 |
| 3 | 530.482937258399 |
| ... | ... |

Here is the code.

```
def create_dataset(dataset, look_back=1):
    dataX, dataY = [], []
    for i in range(len(dataset)-1-look_back):
        a = dataset[i:(i+look_back), 0]
        dataX.append(a)
        dataY.append(dataset[i + look_back, 0])
    return np.array(dataX), np.array(dataY)

# fix random seed for reproducibility
_seed=42
tf.random.set_seed(_seed)
seed(_seed)

# load dataset
ts=gt.copy()

try:
    ts.drop(columns='index', inplace=True)
except:
    print("No index column was found")

# normalize the dataset
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
dataset = scaler.fit_transform(ts)



# split into train and test sets
train_test_threshold=14
train_size = int(len(dataset) -train_test_threshold)
test_size = len(dataset) - train_size
train, test = dataset[0:train_size], dataset[train_size:len(dataset)]

# reshape into X=t and Y=t+1
look_back = 7
trainX, trainY = create_dataset(train, look_back)
testX, testY = create_dataset(test, look_back)

# reshape input to be [samples, time steps, features]
trainX_r = np.reshape(trainX, (trainX.shape[0], trainX.shape[1],1 ))
testX_r = np.reshape(testX, (testX.shape[0], testX.shape[1], 1))

# create and fit the LSTM network
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(4, input_shape=(trainX_r.shape[1],1),return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(2, return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(trainX_r, trainY, epochs=500, batch_size=16, verbose=0)

# make predictions
trainPred = model.predict(trainX_r)
testPred = model.predict(testX_r)

# invert predictions
trainPredict = scaler.inverse_transform(trainPred)
trainY = scaler.inverse_transform([trainY])
testPredict = scaler.inverse_transform(testPred)
testY = scaler.inverse_transform([testY])

plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
plt.figure(figsize=(24,12))
plt.title('1 day ahead Electricity Price Forecasting')
plt.xlabel('Step (1 day)', fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel('Electricity Price (EU)', fontsize=18)
plt.plot(testPredict)
plt.plot(testY.transpose())
plt.legend(['Forecast', 'Actual'])
plt.show()
```

No matter if I change the parameters of the neural network the results remains the same. Can any one tell me where I have done the error in the code?

Here is an image
[image]

It seems like the prediction have moved to the right, predicting one step beyond.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It means that your neural network didn't learn very much. Compare its performance with the [naive forecast](https://otexts.com/fpp3/simple-methods.html), i.e. predicting the previous value

$$
\hat y_t = y_{t-1} 
$$

Very likely the performance of your algorithm would not be better than this. It seems that your model learned exactly that, it is an overtly complicated identity function. That is why it is useful to start with very simple methods before using more complicated ones and use them as benchmarks.

Comment: I would appreciate it if you have any comments on the code as the reason for the model weakness. Is there any error?

Comment: @gbarel It's not a code-review site and reviewing machine learning code without business context and access to the data wouldn't make much sense. But neural networks are not really great for time-series data, so it's not surprising. I already saw several examples as yours, once someone even blogged about it as a success story...